# How to create an specific event foreach component created from array result - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hello everyone here I am again. I want to create an specific event foreach component created from the result of the JSON response.

I've created each component using .map, it works I can create the  **Collapse headers** from the result. If the result from JSON are 3 it creates 3 different headers, but my problem is with the component inside, every time I press the TouchableWithoutFeedBack it renders all the **Collapse Body** based on the last Collapse Header click, but I need to render only the Collapse Body related with clicked Header.

I have a functional component which have a Request to retrieve the categories and fill the Collapse Header, then on the click of the Header I need to fill a custom component based on the Header Category.

How can I solve this? 
If someone could help me, I would really appreciate it.

```
 {auditCategory.map(r =>(

            <Collapse>

                <CollapseHeader key={r.id} >
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=> {
                // console.log("TESTE:"+r.id) 
                axios.get("http://10.113.16.113:8081/api/audititem/findbycategorycheckl?checklistid="+checklistid+"&categoryid="+r.id,{                        
                }).then
                (function (response){
                    setAuditItems(response.data);
                 //   console.log(response.data);      
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
                    }}>
                 <View style={styles.collapHead}>


                 <Text style={styles.collapHeadInput} >{r.categorY_DESCRIPTION} </Text>

                  </View> 
                  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                </CollapseHeader>                
                <CollapseBody>
                 <ScrollView horizontal={true}>

                        {auditItems.map(r =>(
                            <AuditItem key={r.id} title={r.subcategorY_DESCRIPTION}  od={r.od}></AuditItem>
                           ))}

                </ScrollView>
                </CollapseBody>
            </Collapse>

       ))}
```

This is the response from axios.get :

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "subcategorY_DESCRIPTION": " Test 1 SubCategory",
        "checklisT_ID": 1,
        "auditcategorY_ID": 2,
        "od": 300,
        "creatioN_DATETIME": "2020-03-06T00:00:00",
        "status": true,
        "locatioN_ID": 1,
        "shoW_SCANCODE": true,
        "shoW_CAPTUREPHOTO": true,
        "shoW_COMMENTS": true
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "subcategorY_DESCRIPTION": "Test 2",
        "checklisT_ID": 1,
        "auditcategorY_ID": 2,
        "od": 10,
        "creatioN_DATETIME": "2020-04-06T00:00:00",
        "status": true,
        "locatioN_ID": 1,
        "shoW_SCANCODE": true,
        "shoW_CAPTUREPHOTO": true,
        "shoW_COMMENTS": true
    }
]
```

Comment: Make auditItems an object with the keys the id of the outer element. Then you can do `auditItems[key].map`

Comment: Please could you give a little more detailed information on how I can do it? I still starting with React.

Comment: I hope I understood your question. I will try to elaborate in an answer. See below shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using some sort of state object. I am assuming you are using the `useState` hook with something like `const [auditItems, setAuditItems] = useState('')`.

I am suggesting you use an empty object to start. So:
`const [auditItems, setAuditItems] = useState({})`

Then when you retrieve the values you wish to set to `auditItems`, you can set it as a property of the object that already exists. Like so: `setAuditItems({...auditItems, [r.id]: response.data})` Then you can check if the key exists when you render the items:

```
{auditItems[r.id] && auditItems[r.id].map(r =>(
    <AuditItem key={r.id} title={r.subcategorY_DESCRIPTION}  od={r.od}></AuditItem>
))}
```

If you don't care to save the previous values on the next click, you can simply make another state hook that tracks the id currently clicked and use that to conditionally display the `auditItems` map. Or just remove the `...auditItems` from `setAuditItems`.

Any of that make sense?

Comment: Exactly I'm using `const [auditItems, setAuditItems] = useState([]);` , I'll try to do as you suggested, thanks.

Comment: Awesome! Keep us posted!

Comment: When I change the `setAuditItems(response.data);` inside the function(response) to `  setAuditItems({...auditItems, r.id: response.data})` I'm get an error, that it's expecting ","(comma) instead of "."  If I take off the "." it accepts as property, but then on the event to render it, nothing happens like if it is empty.

Comment: Fixed my answer. You need to switch to `setAuditItems({...auditItems, [r.id]: response.data})`. Sorry. I wasn't paying attention. You have to use square brackets in an object literal to use a variable's value as a key.

Comment: It worked with the update, thanks a lot for your help and patience with the explanation.

Comment: Absolutely! Happy to share!

Answer (score 0):

Unless this behaviour is specific to React native or the library of the Collpase, but what I would do is set the current opened Collpase item in local state when the `onPress` is called:

```js
const [openedCollapseItemID, setOpenedCollapseItemID] = useState('')
```

then check if that's the opened one when rendering:

```
 {auditCategory.map(r => (
     <Collapse isCollapsed={r.id === openedCollapseItemID} >
...
     </Collapse>
```

Comment: But the problem is that even if know which one is opened, it will render all of `<AuditItem>` using the category id from the last clicked Collapse Header.